# Discord.js How i get id of members in guild?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

## Discord Version 11.4.2

How i get id of members in that guild?

```js
if(message.content === '!members'){
 var memserver = client.guilds.get(message.guild.id)
 console.log(memserver.users.tag)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading this thread in late 2020 you are probably using Discord.js version 12 or later. In this case the answer above won't work for you.
You need to correct the answer this way:

```js
 if(message.content === '!members'){
    var memserver = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id); // get guild id of that message
    memserver.members.cache.forEach(member => {
        console.log(member.user.id);
 }); // get all user id in server
}
```

as described [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#commonly-used-methods-that-changed)

Answer (score 0):

## Success

```js
if(message.content === '!members'){
    var memserver = client.guilds.get(message.guild.id); // get guild id of that message
    memserver.members.forEach(member => {
      console.log(member.user.id);
 }); // get all user id in server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need get guild. Message object already has property guild, so you can use like this.

```js
if(message.content === '!members'){
    message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
        console.log(member.id)
    })
})
```